# How does r calculate the p-values in logistic regression

Tags: r

What type of p-values do R calculate in a binomial logistic regression, and where is this documented?

When i read the documentation for ?glm() I find no reference to the calculation of the p-values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The p-values are calculated by the function `summary.glm`. See `?summary.glm` for a (very brief) bit about how those are calculated.

For more information, look at the source code by typing

```
summary.glm
```

at the R command prompt. There you will find the lines of code where an object `pvalue` is created. Follow the code back to see how the components of the p-value calculation are (conditionally) calculated.

Comment: Ok in the summary.glm i find this: 

"(...) A fourth column gives the two-tailed p-value corresponding to the t or z ratio based on a Student t or Normal reference distribution(...)" 

So this is what is called a Wald test right?

Comment: @RasmusLarsen, these tests are equivalent to Wald tests. However, search the R-help archives [e.g., here](http://r-project.markmail.org/search/?q=wald+glm+ripley#query:wald%20glm%20ripley+page:2+mid:fswyvij4uavxvnfk+state:results) for some discussion on significance testing in `glm`s

Answer (score 1):

The authors of R wrote the help system with several principles in mind: compactness (don't write more than is needed, it's not a textbook), accuracy, and a curious and well-educated audience. It really *was* written for other statisticians. The "curious" part of that opening sentence was included to raise the question why you did not also follow the various links in the `?glm` page:  to `summary.glm` where you would have found one answer to your ambiguous question or to `anova.glm` where you would have found another possible answer. The help-authors do expect that you will follow those links *and* read the whole page *and* execute the examples. You will notice that even after you get to `summary.glm` that there is no mention of "binary logistic regression" since they pretty much assume that you are well-grounded in statistics and have copy of McCullagh and Nelder handy, or if not that you will go read the references.

The other principle: sometimes it is the code itself (given the open-source nature of R) that performs the documentation. Technically `glm` doesn't print anything and `print.glm` doesn't print p-values. It would be `print.summary.glm` or `print.anova.glm` that would be doing any printing. Part of learning R is learning that the results printed to the console will have gone through a eval-print loop and that output can be tailored with object-class-specific functions.

These assumptions are just part of what many people see as a "steep learning curve for R" (although I would have called it a shallow curve if plotted with time/effort on x-axis.)

Comment: I appreciate you explaining all this to me, including explaining why the question was downvoted. I did not understand this at first but now I begin to understand that the question was unclear and ambigious. I will use this knowledge in the future. I guess i did not follow the link to summary.glm because I wasn't smart enough to realize that it would have given me the answer, and because I was probably looking for something like: The p-values of the coefficients in the model are calculated using the Wald test (given that is the case) :)

Comment: As I said, the authors assumed you were a statistician and would be able to tell from context (with a coefficient, s.e.(coef) and p-value that matched), that these were Wald tests. They also assume that you know that these are not to be trusted and that model comparisons are better done with likelihood ratio tests.